# Passing a memory address in Rust

Tags: reference, rust, memory-address

I have a function where I need to pass a memory address. I only managed to find that we can print out a memory address by using `println!("{:p}", number);`.

How can I access the memory address and use it in a function?

Comment: Where and how is that function created? Rust? FFI from another language?

Comment: I need to put a memory address to a register.

Comment: What is your input type you want a pointer for?

Comment: It's an array of types u16

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rust provides [raw pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.18.0/book/first-edition/raw-pointers.html), `*const T` and `*mut T` for this purpose. You can convert a `usize` to these types, and then dereference or create a Rust reference to that value, in an unsafe block.

Rust references automatically ensure that they are always valid. i.e. if you use one in safe Rust, then value that it references will always be properly initialised, and it won't have been dropped. Once you deal with raw pointers and memory addresses, you are responsible for that yourself, and you can cause some pretty serious problems by getting it wrong.

If you have a value on the stack, you can get it like this:

```
fn main() {
    let my_value = 123;
    // get a reference to the value
    let my_value_ref = &my_value;
    // convert the reference to a raw pointer
    let my_value_raw_ptr = my_value_ref as *const i32;
    // convert the raw pointer to an integer
    let my_value_addr = my_value_raw_ptr as usize;

    println!("address = {:X}", my_value_addr);
}
```

If the value is heap-allocated, then usually there is a provided method to obtain a raw pointer. For example, `Box` and `Rc` have an `into_raw()` method while `String` and `Vec` have `as_ptr()`:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    // get a raw pointer pointer to the data
    let my_vec_ptr = my_vec.as_ptr();
    // convert the raw pointer to an integer
    let my_vec_addr = my_vec_ptr as usize;

    println!("address = {:X}", my_vec_addr);
}
```

Obtaining the address like this is completely safe. However, you will need to use `unsafe` Rust to actually do anything useful with it. It will be up to you to make sure that the value at that address is valid whenever it is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

Rust uses the macros `std::ptr::addr_of!()` and `std::ptr::addr_of_mut!()` to find the memory address of a given variable or expression. The mutability of the two macros is where the primary distinction between them lies:

A raw immutable pointer (*const T) to the provided variable or expression is returned by the function `std::ptr::addr_of!()`.
A raw mutable pointer (*mut T) to the provided variable or expression is returned by the function `std::ptr::addr_of_mut!()`.

These macros come in handy when working with low-level code that requires raw pointers or passing a raw pointer to a function.

Lets say you have a string which is located in Heap memory. (This macro also works for Stack memory.)

```
let s1 = String::from("Hello");
```

You can get memory address by `std::ptr::addr_of!(s1)` and use it however you like.

```
let address = std::ptr::addr_of!(s1);
```

If the variable is mutable than you may use;

```
std::ptr::addr_of_mut!()
```

macro.

Comment: There is no need to use `addr_of[_mut]!()` in this code. They are required only when you cannot create a reference (unaligned, uninitialized data).